# why do I get different results and a result that I'm not expecting

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, return, malloc

I'm expecting for this code (second code) to run only 3 times. but it runs 6 on visual studio, and when I tried it on sololearn playground it run 4 times.

I've done other testing kind of like this code and the while loop never stops running. I thought that if the memory address did not hold any value it would be consider NULL, so it should return a 0, but it does not (for the first code).

well now I know why I'm wrong because is comparing the memory not the value inside the memory which makes sense why this code(first code) "never" stops.

```
///first code
int main() {
    int* s = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 5){
        *(s + i) = i; 
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(s + i != NULL)
    {
        printf("hello");
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

, but then why does the second code stops if it is also comparing the memory address?

```
//second code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int** s = malloc(3 * sizeof(int*));
    int x = 0;
    for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        *(s + x) = malloc(1 * sizeof(int*));
    }


    int i = 0;
    while( *(s + i) != NULL)
    {   
        printf("hello");
        i++;
        
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

And I guess the solution would be just to use a link list right?

Comment: It's converting the `NULL` pointer to the integer `0`, so `0 == NULL` is true and the loop stops immediately.

Comment: Not directly related: don't write `*(s + x)` but write `s[x]`, that's how it's done usually.

Comment: Nothing in your code ever sets anything to `NULL`. So why would you expect comparing things to `NULL` to indicate anything useful?

Comment: In the `while` loop of your second code snippet, you are accessing the array `s` out of bounds, because you are not limiting the value of `i` to `0` to `2`. This invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop:

```
while(*(s + i) != NULL) { 

      printf("hello"); i++;
}
```

You check if the `s[i]`th element is `NULL`. This is a dangerous comparison and leads to undefined behaviour.

Since `s` can only store 3 `int*`, there is absolutely no guarantee there is a `NULL` somewhere in memory near `s`, so running the code will print an arbitrary number of "hello".

If you want to go through the array and check for `NULL` this is a better approach:

```
int i = 0; 

while(i < 3) 
{
    (s[i] != NULL) ? puts("hello") : puts("NULL found");
    i++;
}
```